# set image as submit button

Tags: html, webforms

i am using following code to set an image as submit button

```
 *<input type="submit" src="submit1.jpg" alt="submit Button"onMouseOver="this.src='submit1.jpg'">*
```

but i actually did not know at which place in whole code to put this line of code because i put it after  but it is not working

at which place i put this code there appear "submit query" but i want it to submit query at buuto i also use

```
input type="image"
```

actually i want to ask from which place i start this code "from which line?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change type from input to image and add value as submit:

```
<input type="image" value="submit" src="submit1.jpg" alt="submit Button" onMouseOver="this.src='submit1.jpg'">
```

Answer (score 5):

This is complete HTML document:

```
<form name="someform" action="http://www.google.com">
<input type="image" width="100" value="submit" src="image1.png" alt="submit Button" onMouseOut="this.src='image1.png'" onMouseOver="this.src='image2.png'">
</form>
```

Note that "onmouseout" event is used to bring the button to previous form when mouse is not over